# Extract values between characters in mysql?

Tags: mysql, replace

I am stuck with a problem, I am a beginner in mysql and I was assigned to create a query that extracts values from url addresses. So basically I have thousands of url addresses like this for example 'https://www.google.com/search?source=' where I need to extract everything from '://www' till the first '/'(in this case 'google.com'), basically the domain. And it's not that simple, sometimes it's http, sometimes it's  'https://google.com/search?source=' without www etc. I am up to here but I feel helpless, any suggestions?

```
select distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'://',0) col from table where length(col) - length(replace(col, '://', '')) >= 1 
         and length(col) - length(replace(col, '/', '')) >= 1 
                and col = 'value'
                    and col <> ''
                      and col is not null 
                        order by date
                         limit 600;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Query like this:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX (
     SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'https://www.google.com/search?source=', '/',3),
 '/', -1);
```

Sample:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'https://www.google.com/search?source=', '/',3) , '/', -1);
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'https://www.google.com/search?source=', '/',3) , '/', -1) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| www.google.com                                                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: That's all good but I needed ti extract google.com, not www.google.com and my problem is that sometimes the address starts with https://www or with http:// or http://www...I need only google.com without any https:// or www